# Rest API C# set or update lookup field by relationship name?

Tags: rest-api

We have a connected app that is updating records through the Rest API using c#. 
I would like to not have to use the ID to set a lookup field and instead use the name. In an upsert, what I am describing would look like this: Object__r.Name = "Rest API Update Name", however, I can not seem to make a relationship update using the Rest API. Am I using it wrong, or is that a limitation of the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you can only set the lookup relationship field using either:

- the exact record Id, or by
- using an external Id field on the object you are referencing.

The Name field wouldn't meet the external id requirement.

See [Give lookup field External Id in JSON request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/55073/102).

Comment: Perfect, that was the answer I was seeking. Thank you Daniel. Edit:Spelling