# How to refer to an existing record in REST API composite JSON?

Tags: rest-api, relationships, master-detail, externalid

When using REST API composite JSON, how to refer with external id

- an existing record
- to existing Master-Detail parent from a newly created child

We have the following objects:

- `Organization__c`:

  - Has `Organization__c` that is an External ID

    - ID comes from another system
    - A bit confusing since the field name is the same
  - (A bunch of other fields)
- `Foobar__c`:

  - Has `Organization__c` field as Master-Detail(Organization)
  - (A bunch of other fields)

We're trying to create Foobar objects from another system that knows only external id for Organization.

We're trying to POST to `services/data/v42.0/composite/tree/Foobar__c` with `"Organization__r": {"Organization__c": "123456"}` for organization reference but get the following error: `{"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"referenceId":"ref-1","errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"Cannot reference a foreign key field Organization__r.","fields":[]}]}]}`

I tried also with `"Organization__c": {"Organization__c": "123456"}` but got: `[{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_OBJECT value { or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:398]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]` My hypothesis here is that by using `Organization__c` I'm trying to create a new Organization record and that fails because there are fields missing.

UPDATE/ADDITION: Approach with `Organization__r": {"Organization__c": "123456"}` seems to work both

- When inserting a single Foobar object with REST API (POST to `/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Foobar__c`)

  - See e.g. [Give lookup field External Id in JSON request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55073/give-lookup-field-external-id-in-json-request)
- With Bulk API

  - See e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm under "Relationship Fields for Custom Objects"

Comment: Similar issue seems to be discussed at least in https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BhY8QAK, no solution there :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you only have two options here. The first is a "chatty" solution where your first step is to query `Organization__c` for the record ID.

```
/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+from+Organization__c+where+Organization__c+=+'<yourExternalId>'
```

Given that record Id, you should be able to then POST your foobar__c records directly now that you have both the SF record Id and the External Id.

It's two API calls, but should work.

As an alternative, you can write a Custom Apex REST endpoint that effectively does the same lookup from `Organization__c.Organization__c` to SF record Id.

I don't think that there is any other way to get around looking up the SF Record Id of the Master.