# Problem importing data with standard lookup via Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, import

So problem is with Contact records. There is required lookup field called Account Name ( API Account ). So i did download records with SFDX commend :

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export --query "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Account.ExternalID__c, CurrencyIsoCode, Phone, MailingAddress, email FROM Contact" --prefix demo-data --outputdir FixedData --plan
```

But when i try to then use this :

```
sfdx force:data:tree:import -u test-kul2gyl6amir@example.com -f FixedDane\demo-data-Contacts.json
```

I do get error:

> === ContactRef1 [1] STATUSCODE     MESSAGE                                        FIELDS ─────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────── 
>   ────── INVALID_FIELD  Cannot reference a foreign key field Account.

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Contact",
                "referenceId": "ContactRef1"
            },
            "FirstName": "Villllli",
            "LastName": "BuyNow",
            "Account": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Account",
                    "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/0010E00000PQAnHQAX"
                },
                "ExternalID__c": "000000000000000001"
            },
            "CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
            "Phone": "33 810 22 32",
            "MailingAddress": {
                "city": "Kraków",
                "country": "Poland",
                "countryCode": "PL",
                "geocodeAccuracy": null,
                "latitude": null,
                "longitude": null,
                "postalCode": "33-332",
                "state": null,
                "stateCode": null,
                "street": "Juliana Dunajewskiego 1"
            },
            "Email": "at@at.at"
        }
    ]
}
```

I did add to Account object field ExternalId and marked it as external Id field. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a fundamental problem if both nested records are to be created and at the same time the link to another object is to be established on the basis of a relationship.

Similar problems are described here:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BhY8QAK
- [How to refer to an existing record in REST API composite JSON?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208710/how-to-refer-to-an-existing-record-in-rest-api-composite-json/208789)

A solution has unfortunately not been posted anywhere yet.

**UPDATE**: 
It seems that it doesn't work when using "composite/tree". 
I solved the problem by dividing the call into multiple subrequests and using the composite resource. 
This makes it possible to create the record and link it to the parent in a first step, then get the ID and finally create the child records - all in one request.

You will find a detailed description and examples here:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm

In your case, I would first create the contact and link it to the account. Then retrieve the ID of the contact and finally assign the mailing address to the contact using the ID.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different way to achieve the problem you have.

You should redesign your query as parent-to-child query, like following

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export --query "SELECT Name, ExternalID__c, (SELECT FirstName, LastName, CurrencyIsoCode, Phone, MailingAddress, email FROM Contacts) FROM Account" --prefix demo-data --outputdir FixedData --plan
```

and then run import

```
sfdx force:data:tree:import -u test-kul2gyl6amir@example.com  test-kul2gyl6amir@example.com -p FixedData/demo-data-Account-Contact-plan.json
```

It works for the one-level deep, if multiple levels required, two exports can be done and then the plan files should be merger into one, where the intermediate object should have both properties `"saveRefs": true` and `"resolveRefs": true` set to true

Answer (score 0):

So to solve my problem ( i did it before A. Kaspar answer ) i made a code that change my filed downloaded with SFDX in to compoisteAPI files and I push them with regular API requests.

I will check Kaspar answer today and will try to give you guys info on which options is easier to perform.

To those who do not know what compositeAPI is:
https://tddprojects.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SF/pages/451477505/Composite+APIs