# create an opportunity with a related campaign using the campaign name

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, campaign

I've loaded opportunity data using the data loader, but I'd like to load new records directly from the REST API. When I load the data from the data loader application step 2b allows me to select lookup fields on related objects such as the name from the campaign object.

The challenge I'm facing is that when I review the Object Reference in the REST API I don't see a documented way to implement a similar lookup. Am I limited to creating a relationship from an opportunity to a campaign using IDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give lookup field External Id in JSON request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55073/give-lookup-field-external-id-in-json-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read the [Insert or Update (Upsert) a Record Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm) documentation.

Here's a minimum viable payload:

```
{ "Name": "Test",
  "CloseDate": "2024-03-01",
  "StageName": "Prospecting",
  "Campaign": {
    "Name": "The Campaign to End All Campaigns"
  },
  "Account": {
    "Name": "salesforce.com"
  }
}
```

You simply specify the relationship name, and provide a valid external ID.